# Load image as background with css sprites

Tags: css

To lighten the load of pages, I was thinking to using the sprites. My problem is that I have an image as background of a `li` and another image between it.
I'd like to load all that images with sprites but can I use a class as background of a `li`?
If I load 2 or pus images as sprites I'll have a single image that contains all my images and with css I can choose which display. For example: this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THgwl.png I can choose which of this 4 images display like on the snippet I left.
Can I do the same thing like this with a `li`?

```
<li class="icon advice chrome">content</li>
```

```css
.icon {
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/THgwl.png);
}
.advice {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.chrome {
    background-position:-0px -0px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.firefox {
    background-position:-0px -80px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.facebook {
    background-position:-0px -160px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.twitter {
    background-position:-0px -240px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/chrome" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKyLm.gif" border="0" width="1" height="1" class="icon advice chrome" title="Google Chrome" alt="Chrome" /></a>
 <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKyLm.gif" border="0" width="1" height="1" class="icon advice firefox" title="Firefox" alt="Firefox" /></a><br />
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKyLm.gif" border="0" width="1" height="1" class="icon advice facebook" title="" alt="Facebook"/></a>
 <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKyLm.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="icon advice twitter" title="" alt="Twitter"/></a>
```

Comment: have you tried to run it? Looks like its working to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use a single class to call background image but you need to define background position for other classes for example see my fiddle

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/52fka569/2/)

i have used `.sprite` class to call background image for `<li>` and `<a>` also but i have added another class for `background position`

Comment: Indeed without `background-position` crashes everything. Thanks!